# Alert to appear on right top corner using ui-bootstrap, bootstrap with Angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want my Alert to appear on the right hand corner. How would I do that using bootstrap?. Currently my HTML look like this.

```
  <div class="notification">
        <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"  close="alert.close()">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
      </div>
```

I am using ui-bootstrap for angular and twitter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: thank you for the link, learning css

Answer (score 7):

for someone like me :)

```
 .notification{
      position: fixed;
      top: 10em;
      right: 10em;
    }
```